# XNA Redistributable missing from Publish Prerequisites options

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna, redistributable

I've gotten XNA running perfectly fine on Visual Studio 2012 and publishing, installing and running the game works fine as well on any computers that already have the XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0 installed but when I attempt to install on a computer that doesn't already have it, the install fails due to it being missing. Furthermore, it isn't even an option in the Prerequisites menu on the program's publish properties.

When I open up an older project, the option exists but with a yellow exclamation triangle and I don't believe it is actually being set.

Does anyone know how I can add the XNA Redistributable back into the Prerequisites options?

Comment: Are you using `ClickOnce`?

Comment: I am, and am facing the same issue as the OP. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To be truthful, I've never personally used the Prerequisites feature for formal exporting of projects. However, it's a very common thing for applications to install the redistributables for their dependencies before installation, so I took a quick peek around and found that there are a couple of different programs which will generate installers for you which also take into account checking for and installing missing dependencies. It looks like the most popular one is [WiX XNA Installer](https://xnainstaller.codeplex.com/). However, for a *much* more thorough examination of this topic and the different routes that you could take, I would suggest looking at [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/how-do-i-create-an-installer-for-my-xna-demo) by Ray Dey.