# Visual Studio 2013 does not show XNA Redistributable option in the Publish Prerequisites section

Tags: xna, visual-studio-2013, redistributable

I have XNA 4.0 and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

I can convert an old XNA game and it runs on my development computer with no problem. I can create a new XNA game and it runs on my development computer with no problem.

When I try to run the games on any other computer, they don’t run because it’s not installing the prerequisite XNA Redistributable.

The XNA Redistributable does not appear as a prerequisite option on the “Publish” > “Prerequisite” page in VS.

Someone else had the exact same problem, but no one answered the question:

[XNA Redistributable missing from Publish Prerequisites options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981495/xna-redistributable-missing-from-publish-prerequisites-options)

Does anyone know how to add an option to the “Prerequisite” menu in VS?

Answer (score 0):

For what I remeber from school this year, they said that Visual Studio 2012 or higher didn't work well with XNA. What I can recommand you that may solve the problem until you find a clear answer for it is to get back to [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=23691). I used it all the time this year and publishing worked without problems.

Good Luck with your games.